# Set child Adapter on click of listview item

Tags: android

I am trying to load child list on click of Listview item. Because i want a list in horizontal should be open on click of listview item.So that i am taking two listview in horizontal,one for parent and another for child.on click of parent list item child item on right side should be loaded.But i am not able to do it. kindly help me.

Code which i had tried:

```
  lvparent.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {

                    String pos = alparent.get(position).toString();
                    int posi = parent.getPositionForView(view);
                    view.setSelected(true);

                    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                        if (al.get(i).category_name.equalsIgnoreCase(pos)) {
                            int ids = al.get(i).id;
                            for (int j = 0; i < al.size() - 1; j++) {
                                if (al.get(j).category_parent_name.equals(String.valueOf(ids))) {
                                    alchild.add(al.get(j).category_name);

                                }
                            }

                        if(alchild.size()>0) {
                            lvchild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            adchild=new ArrayAdapter<String>(NavigationActivity.this,R.layout.list_white_text, android.R.id.text1,alchild);
                            lvchild.setAdapter(adchild);
                            adchild.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lvchild.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        } else {
                            //  continue;
                        }
                    }
```